# "Scroll down to update" (or left) feature on overflown div

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In the same way Twitter apps for smartphones do in terms of updating the tweets list, I'd like to be notified when -using touchs- I scroll an overflown `div` further from its limits.

Supponsing `wrapper` is the `div`'s `id`, I've tried to check for `wrapper.scrollWidth`, `scrollLeft`, `clientWidth` and `clientLeft` with no success. Those values stay the same even taking the scroll bar out of its limits.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The feature I'm looking for seems to be known as "scroll down to update", on Twitter/Facebook apps (and many more, for sure).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$(wrapper).scrollTop()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Instead of Top I've made use of Left, but it remais the same as wrapper.scrollLeft (or scrollTop in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You can likely use mandatory snap points to force the app to "snap back" to the end of your scroll region when the user releases the scroll. This would allow you to watch the scollLeft (or scrollTop) change, and then watch it until the user releases (When it starts to reverse).

Challenge is that the user can use the mouse to scroll past the mandatory snappoint; you  might need to detect the interaction, and change it to a scroll boundary.

Details on mandatory snap points:

[Guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465310.aspx)

[Snap point declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Snap Point Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)